# How to fix this division script so it won't display decimal results

Tags: javascript

So I have this script (see the entire HTML below) that displays random divisions and the results whenever the equal symbol is clicked. What I am want to do is have the divisor be any 2 digits random number and the quotient be a full number. no decimals. So for example if the generated divisor is 81, for the quotient to be a full number the dividend should only be 1, 3, 9 or 81. If the divisor is 44, the dividend should only be 1, 2, 4, 11, 22, 44 ( I forgot what this number are called, I'm sure they have a name in Maths).

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const buttonRoolDice = document.querySelector('.dice-roll');

  function rollDice() {

    const diceSide1 = document.getElementById('dice-side-1');
    const diceSide2 = document.getElementById('dice-side-2');
    const status = document.getElementById('status');

    const side1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    const side2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
    const diceTotal = side1 / side2;

    diceSide1.innerHTML = side1;
    diceSide2.innerHTML = side2;

    status.innerHTML = '' + diceTotal + '';

    if (side1 === side2) {
      //   status.innerHTML += ' Doubles! You get a free turn!';
    }
  }

  buttonRoolDice.addEventListener('click', rollDice, false);

}, false);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#status {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dice {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.dice-roll {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="dice-side-1" class="dice">0</div>
    <span style="font-size: 200px;"> : </span>
    <div id="dice-side-2" class="dice">0</div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="column">
    <button type="button" class="dice-roll dice"> = </button>
    <h2 id="status"></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe "factors" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: yeap, that's the word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get factors of divisor, You can use this function:

```
function factors(x){
    var factors = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        if (x % i === 0){
            factors.push(i)
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Now from returned array choose (maybe randomly) one of them and place in dividend, then your quotient must be a full number (not decimal). You can use this code:

```
const sideFactors = factors(side1);  
const side2 = sideFactors[Math.floor(Math.random() * sideFactors.length)];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. So I don't open another question, can you please tell me how to make the dividend (the factor) to be only one digit numbers?

Comment: You can define a variable for your loop like this: `var cond = x > 9 ? 9 : x;`
and use cond variable in your for loop : `for (let i = 1; i <= cond; i++)`